# I get null from spring filter on curl request

Tags: java, python, spring, curl, filter

**type1**

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8200/api/' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer test11' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'test1=1' \
--data-urlencode 'test2=1' \
--data-urlencode 'test3=1' \
--data-urlencode 'test4=false' \
--data-urlencode 'test5=false'
```

**type2**

```
curl -k -v -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Authorization: Token test11" 
-d 'test1'='1' 
-d 'test2'='1' 
-d 'test3'='false,' 
-d 'test4'='false,' 
-d 'test5'='false' http://127.0.0.1:8200/api/
```

The request above is possible, but the request below fails.
When requesting with type2, the following result value is returned as null.

```
@Bean
public Filter snakeConverter() {
    return new OncePerRequestFilter() {

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(
                HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response,
                FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            final Map<String, String[]> formattedParams = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

            for (String param : request.getParameterMap().keySet()) {
                String formattedParam =
                        CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, param);
                formattedParams.put(formattedParam, request.getParameterValues(param));
            }

            filterChain.doFilter(
                    new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
                        @Override
                        public String getParameter(String name) {
                            return formattedParams.containsKey(name)
                                    ? formattedParams.get(name)[0]
                                    : null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames() {
                            return Collections.enumeration(formattedParams.keySet());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
                            return formattedParams.get(name);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
                            return formattedParams;
                        }
                    },
                    response);

        }
    };
}
```

The above code is the spring filter I am currently applying.
What is the difference between requesting?
what filter do i need to add??
Why is it null?

Comment: Remove the comma in the value ( , ) -> ' false, '  , also test3 value is different in both requests.